# mail with body/message from remote file over ssh + attachment

Tags: ssh, mail

With `mail` (from `mailutils`), the only way to send an email that has an html message *and* an attachment is to include the message from a file, like this:

```
mail \
--content-type=text/csv --attach=/tmp/filename.csv \
-a "From: sender@example.com" \
-s "An HTML Email with Attachment, Yay!" \
--content-type=text/html \
recipient@example.com < /tmp/filename.txt
```

What I need to do however is grab that last file (`filename.txt` is the one with the html in it) from a remote server.

I can ssh into the remote server no problems with a key, e.g.,

`ssh user@123.456.789.0`

But when I try to point the `mail` command to that location on the remote server, I get "no such file or directory", but there's no question the file is there.

```
mail \
--content-type=text/csv --attach=/tmp/filename.csv \
-a "From: sender@example.com" \
-s "An HTML Email with Attachment, Yay!" \
--content-type=text/html \
recipient@example.com < ssh user@123.456.789.0:/tmp/filename.txt
```

I've tried every combination of backtics and pipes I can think of but I can't get it to work.

By the way, yes, the user from the local server is able to view and open and edit the remote file when logged in as the user on the remote server over ssh.

So

```
ssh user@123.456.789.0
nano /tmp/filename.txt
```

works fine.

Any ideas?

For the time being I'm just copying the file over to the other server before sending the email but I'd rather not have to do that. Much prefer a one-liner.

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 on both servers. Using postfix with mailutils.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try replacing

```
... < ssh user@123.456.789.0:/tmp/filename.txt
```

by

```
... <<< `ssh user@123.456.789.0 cat /tmp/filename.txt`
```

ssh can only execute a remote command, /tmp/filename.txt is not a command, thus the error.

Alternatively, can you use pipe

```
ssh user@123.456.789.0 cat /tmp/filename.txt | mail ...
```

Comment: I had tried that, but I tried it again. Still getting no such file or directory.

Comment: see my updated response, use "<<< ``" or place ssh command to the beginning. Tested and worked fine on my Ubuntu.

Comment: Beautiful. Working perfectly. A bunch of thanks.